# How to determine what width and height to use in Android Studio layout and a possible way to recreate this design ?

Tags: java, android, layout

i am trying to recreate and redecorate this layout. I put some ImageButtons , but the problem can't make them to stick together like the image below , I tried to set up the width and the height but android phones are with different screen sizes , so when i set the width to 200dp and the height to 200dp , everything seemes nice. However i tried the layout on a device with bigger screen and its totally messed up. Please can you suggest me a better way to recreate this design or to set up the images buttons to fit perfectly on all devices. Thank you in advance.  [image]

Comment: i prefer to do this programatically, first get the device size and then adjust the width and height of layout, if you still want to use xml you can set it to hidden at start with any values, then resize them dynamically and change visibility to visible

Comment: @Rico I think LinearLayout is more reliable and easier here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with multiple `LinearLayout`'s. For example one for every row. In each `LinearLayout` you assign `android:orientation="horizontal"` and `android:layout_width="0dp"`, `android:layout_height="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` for the icons. After you have a `LinearLayout` for every row you can make a final `LinearLayout` which has `android:orientation="vertical"` and there put all the `Layout`'s with the icons in it with `<include layout="..." android:layout_height="0dp"`android:layout_width="match_parent"`android:layout_weight="1"/>`.

**What does width with 0dp and weight do?**

It makes that every icon has a evenly distributed width.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I will try this. What should be android:layout_height then?

Comment: Sorry for being too stupid , i am new in Android Programming, can you tell me how to put all the layouts i made in the vertical layout? And should i put an icon inside every layout or all icons in the final layout. Thank you sir!

Comment: You go to res folder to layout. In there you create a (rightclick ->) new Layout resource file for every row. You make the Layout a LinearLayout. In there you just put your two icons (as it looks like on the picture) and after that you make one more LinearLayout where your `<include>` all your other LinearLayouts (which contain the icons) and then you should have it.

Comment: Yes ,  in every layout i made(3layouts horizontal and 1 vertical) , it fits perfect. In every layout i have 2 icons , and i  want those 2 icons to fill my layout but their height is 1/2 of the layout heght.. The width is perfect tho.
EDIT: I did it. Thank you sir , you are the best.

Comment: @Freddie even more glad I could help you.